# SLF4J error when running Grails application created with Application Forge

Tags: grails, slf4j

I used Grails Application Forge with Angular profile to create a test app, but when trying to run it, I get these errors in Intellij:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I tried to follow what is described in the link, but am not sure what to do, to be honest.
I've found dozens of similar problems and solutions but none of them worked for me.

This test app uses Grails 5.1.3. I've got a project which runs on Grails 3.3.14 and I have no issues with the SLF4J.

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Does the app still run successfully?

Comment: Yes, it does run successfully.

Comment: Are you asking what the messages mean, how to make them go away, or something else?

Comment: I think I know what it means. I would like to make them away, I mean I want SLF4J to work properly. I'm sure it's something basic, but I just can't get my head around class paths in Intellij.

Comment: I added slf4j manually in gradle.build like this ```implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36"``` but the error is still there.